# Running docker image with argument

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, microservices, docker-machine

I am working with spring-boot along with docker images.

I am running my **`springboot`** application directly from **`IntelliJ`** name as **`runtime`** with some of argument like below

**`-DCONFIG_DIR=D:\baseapimanager\runtime\config`**

I am able to run it successfully.

But by creating a docker image and running that image, it's not able to run.
As i am not aware about how to pass argument while running docker image.

Here i had shared my Docker file contents as well.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/docker-runtime.jar docker-runtime.jar
EXPOSE 8091
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","docker-runtime.jar"]
```

And running below docker command i am trying to create image file for same.

**`docker build -f Dockerfile -t docker-runtime .`**

After this executing below command to run  this generated image file.

**`docker run -p 8091:8091 docker-runtime`**

Without passing that argument and commenting business with that argument, it's working perfectly fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had made below changes in my Docker file.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/docker-runtime.jar docker-runtime.jar
EXPOSE 8091
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","-DCONFIG_DIR=/shareddata","docker-runtime.jar"]
```

And while running an image i had bind that address using below command , and it's working fine.

**`docker run -p 8091:8091 --mount type=bind,source=/c/Users/lenovo/data,target=/shareddata docker-runtime`**

This had resolved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If CONFIG_DIR is a parameter you consume with Spring configuration `@Value` or `@ConfigurationProperties` you can pass the parameter as environment variable as well.

Environment variables can be passed to the container with `-e`

```
docker run -p 8091:8091 -e CONFIG_DIR=D:\baseapimanager\runtime\config docker-runtime
```

But as D:\baseapimanager\runtime\config looks like a Windows path that will not be visible inside the Docker container you have to add the configs to the docker image as well or mount a docker volume and the the parameter must point to the volume.

Comment: How to add config to docker image?

Comment: Hello @Simon, I want to map `D://` drive for bind source directory but it's not working. with `C://` drive it's working fine as mentioned below
  `docker run -p 8091:8091 --mount type=bind,source=/c/Users/lenovo/data,target=/shareddata docker-runtime`

Answer (score 0):

So to pass an argument into docker build do the following....

1. ARG -DCONFIG_DIR

add the above line in the docker compose file.....

2. $-DCONFIG_DIR

use the above in the dockerfile and access the variable

3. docker-compose build --build-arg -DCONFIG_DIR = ''